# Index error index 14238 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
%pylab inline

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import random
import time
import scipy
import sklearn.feature_extraction
import pickle

from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
bedsizes = {'None':0,
       'Rest All':1}
invbedsizes = {v: k for k, v in bedsizes.items()} 

model = joblib.load('model_bed_size.pkl')
vocab = pickle.load(open('dictionary', 'rb'))
var=pd.read_csv('Train_variables.csv')
dtest = pd.read_csv('/home/ubuntu/test_null_new.csv', usecols=   ("Bed_size","title","short_description","long_description","primary_shelf.all_paths_str","attributes.all_shelves.0","attributes.all_shelves.1","attributes.all_shelves.2","attributes.all_shelves.3","attributes.all_shelves.4","attributes.type.0","attributes.type.1","attributes.type.2","item_id","last_updated_at"),encoding='ISO-8859-1')
lentest = len(dtest)
vocab=vocab["Vocabulary"].to_dict()

Xall = []
i=1
for col in var['Variable']:
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, vocabulary=(vocab[i]),          token_pattern = '\\b\\w+\\b')
    Xall.append(vectorizer.transform(dtest[col].astype(str)))
    j=i
    i=j+1
    print (col, 'Done', shape(Xall[-1]))
Xspall = scipy.sparse.hstack(Xall)
X_test_final = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(Xspall)
print (shape(X_test_final))   
ypred = model.decision_function(X_test_final)
ypredc = model.classes_[np.argmax(ypred, axis = 0)]   

ypredcon = (np.max(ypred, axis = 1) + 2.) / 8. 
ypredcon[ypredcon < 0.] = 0 .
ypredcon[ypredcon > 1.] = 1.

dfinal = pd.DataFrame()
dfinal['item_id '] = dtest['item_id']
dfinal['Predictions'] = ypredc
dfinal['Predictions'].replace(invbedsizes, inplace = True)
dfinal['confidence_score'] = ypredcon
```

The above code is giving an Index error saying that index 14328 is out of bounds for axis 0 and size 2. 
The error is coming at this line
ypredc = model.classes_[np.argmax(ypred, axis = 0)]
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the variables in your code, the error indicates that at

```
 ypred = model.decision_function(X_test_final)
 ypredc = model.classes_[np.argmax(ypred, axis = 0)]   

 error: index 14328 is out of bounds for axis 0 and size 2
```

`model.classes_` is 1 or more dimensions, and the first is size 2, in other words `2 rows/classes`, and possibly many columns.

`ypred` is probably quite large, and `np.argmax(ypred...)` is the index of its largest values (along axis 0), i.e. 14328.

Maye the correct use is `model.classes_[:, np.argmax...]`.

You need to look at the shape of `ypred, and`model.classes_`, and possibly other variables in this area.

Comment: Is there any permanent fix for this? I tried this when I had multiple classes but now as I am trying this for 2 classes it is giving this error.

Comment: The fix is to understand what dimensions each of the arrays has, and use them appropriately.  In other words, don't try to fudge.  Understand the problem and do it right.

Comment: Actually for (X_test_final) the array is 2D but for (ypred) its coming as 1D, so can it be the problem?